# Getting variable from header Angular 2

Tags: angular, variables, header, httprequest, angular2-services

I would like to get 'Total' data from header but it seems like there are only 4 variables there when Postman shows more. Response body is fine, I just can't access to headers properly in the component. How can I do that?
 If any informations are missing, I will edit post as soon as possible. 
Service function:

```
     public getAdverts(searchParams){
let url = 'https://znajdzspeca.herokuapp.com/search/jobs'
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

if(searchParams.localization instanceof Array)
 searchParams.localization = searchParams.localization[0]

let body = JSON.stringify(searchParams)

return this.http.post(url, body, {headers: headers})
.map(response =>  response)
}
```

Component  function using that service:

```
private getAdverts(searchAdvert){
this.advertService.getAdverts(this.searchAdvert)
  .subscribe(

    response => {
      var totalPages = (response.headers.get('Total'));
      console.log(totalPages);
      console.log(response);
      this.results = response.json()


    },
    error => console.log(error))
    }
    }
```

Console & postman logs
[http://i64.tinypic.com/206ouao.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWhcu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you map your response. Headers can be reached from the response itself. So you need to remove the map operator.

```
 /*.map(response =>  response)*/ <----
       .subscribe((res) => {
         var yourData = res.json();
         var headers = res.headers;
       });
```

Be careful with CORS with accessing the response headers. Remember that the custom headers will be visible in same domain. However, for the crossdomain situation, the server has to send Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-Foo, ... header to make the custom headers visible.

Comment: Super! Can you please mark answer as useful? Thanks.

Comment: I did what I can right now, not enough reputation yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I appreciate it.